# UNNEST ARRAY and UNION ALL to other TABLES with String Value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently I have two CTEs each looking at the same table. In one I am dealing with regular records.

```
WITH unsubscribe_logs AS (
        SELECT Subscriber_Key                                                                                 AS cust_sf_id,
            'Email Unsubscribe'                                                                               AS engagement_type,
            Email_Att1                                                                                        AS campaign_code,
            PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', Insert_Local_DT)                                          AS engagement_datetime,
            Email_Name                                                                                        AS details,
            CAST(NULL as STRING)                                                                              AS url,
            CAST(NULL as STRING)                                                                              AS link_name,
            CAST(NULL as STRING)                                                                              AS domain,
            unsubscribe_type                                                                                  AS sub_engagement_type,
            JobID                                                                                             AS job_id,
            CAST(NULL as INT64)                                                                               AS list_id,
            CAST(NULL as INT64)                                                                               AS batch_id,
            source_timestamp                                                                                  AS source_timestamp,
            ingestion_timestamp                                                                               AS ingestion_timestamp
        FROM `dl_salesforce_marketingcloud_uk.behaviour_log_salesforce_daily_unsubscribe_v1`
        WHERE 1=1
            AND CAST(source_timestamp AS date) >= IFNULL(filter_date,"1990-01-01")
),

 unsubscribe_logs_part_two AS (
        SELECT Subscriber_Key                                                                                 AS cust_sf_id,
            'Email Unsubscribe'                                                                               AS engagement_type,
            Email_Att1                                                                                        AS campaign_code,
            PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', Insert_Local_DT)                                          AS engagement_datetime,
            Email_Name                                                                                        AS details,
            CAST(NULL as STRING)                                                                              AS url,
            CAST(NULL as STRING)                                                                              AS link_name,
            CAST(NULL as STRING)                                                                              AS domain,
            JobID                                                                                             AS job_id,
            CAST(NULL as INT64)                                                                               AS list_id,
            CAST(NULL as INT64)                                                                               AS batch_id,
            source_timestamp                                                                                  AS source_timestamp,
            ingestion_timestamp                                                                               AS ingestion_timestamp,
            split (unsubscribe_type, " and ")                                                                 AS unsub_type_parts
        From `pah_andrew_test.unsubscribe_testing`
        WHERE 1=1
            AND unsubscribe_type != 'Marketing' AND unsubscribe_type != 'Reminder' AND unsubscribe_type != ''
            AND CAST(source_timestamp AS date) >= IFNULL(filter_date,"1990-01-01")
),

all_salesforce_engagement as
                  (SELECT
                        NULLIF(cust_sf_id, '')                                                                            as cust_sf_id,
                        engagement_type                                                                                   as engagement_type,
                        NULLIF(campaign_code, '')                                                                         as campaign_code,
                        engagement_datetime                                                                               as engagement_datetime,
                        NULLIF(details, '')                                                                               as details,
                        NULLIF(url, '')                                                                                   as url,
                        NULLIF(link_name, '')                                                                             as link_name,
                        NULLIF(domain, '')                                                                                as domain,
                        NULLIF(TRIM(sub_engagement_type), '')                                                             as sub_engagement_type,
                        CAST(job_id AS STRING)                                                                            as job_id,
                        CAST(list_id AS STRING)                                                                           as list_id,
                        CAST(batch_id AS STRING)                                                                          as batch_id,
                        source_timestamp                                                                                  as source_timestamp,
                        ingestion_timestamp                                                                               as ingestion_timestamp

                  FROM
                                (SELECT * FROM unsubscribe_logs
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT * EXCEPT (unsub_type_parts) FROM unsubscribe_logs_part_two LEFT JOIN unnest(unsub_type_parts) as sub_engagement_type)),
```

I then need to union all the two CTEs there is a mismatch in the type so is there a way to cast my null values which come through as numeric values when split? or a way to just stop the union all query from failing.

Understand this may not be best but learning SQL on the job so any help is appreciated. Basically i need to stop the mismatch so that the CTE can deal with the numeric type after the unnest.

Comment: You  need to use this format  “table_name.field” in the UNNEST  part in the query. “unnest(Table.unsub_type_parts) ”